# Include two headers

Tags: headers

My website has only one header. I want to change it with that of Wordpress, for example, because It has an address with a logo at the top and then menu bar.

How can I add that template to mine?

Answer (score 1):

Use custom header-templates.

create a file for example "header-home.php". Put your code in it and then get it by using 
`<?php get_header('home'); ?>`

You can also use header-templates inside a other header-template. Lets say you have the top navigation. You want it in all headers. Then put the code for this in your header.php. Then in for example header-home.php you write:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> // Loads your header.php
// Some code here
```

And then in for example your index/home file you put only the code `<?php get_header('home'); ?>`

Comment: Sorry! I am completely new to wordpress. this is the information in the header php. I wonder how I can add "department of linguistics" at top of my current header.

Comment: <?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package Tesseract
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

Comment: Just use regular HTML/CSS